# Pull Requests: Referencing code in comment replies

Tags: azure-devops

I know you can go to the files section of a PR and click to add a comment that references code. But is there any markdown or other method that lets you add a reference to some code in the replies to comments?

note: I mean referencing code from a file, not just pasting in the code. I'd like the code to update dynamically similar to code referenced when creating a comment with a file/line reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a statement in [Syntax guidance for basic Markdown usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops): **Note: Code attachments aren't permitted in PR comments**

[image]

So I am afraid it is not support in Markdown.

You can try to click the "`Copy link to this selection`" option for a piece of code in a file and then insert the generated link into the comment reply to achieve the reference.

[image]

[image]